# VLD doesnot detect memory leak whereas CRT Debug shows memory leak

Tags: debugging, crt

Mine is a legacy code and somewhere long time back memory leak was introduced.
I am using

`_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );`

which implicitly calls `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` upon termination/exit from anywhere in code. I am aware of the fact that if we call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` explicitly and some global object is there then memory leak will be reported. That is why not calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` directly.

Get memory leaks and since I am using "new' throughout thecode exact line number and file name are not coming (inspite of declaring #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC). I have 3 options:

```
1. Use VLD: but it does not report any leaks.
2. Override new operator so that CRT works. But get error that new is redefined. actually since it is a huge code base, some other place has overriden it conflicts are arising
3. Use number in curly braces and use _crtbreakalloc , but that number is not stable across runs. thus cannot use this strategy as well.
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Any better mem leak detecting tools?? I used Valgrind on Linux as well. It also doesnot report any mem leak. Only CRT debug reports.